# How to configure maxAge for the default producer factory?

Tags: spring-kafka

On https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#overview-2 the following is stated:

> Starting with version 2.5.8, you can now configure the maxAge property on the producer factory. This is useful when using transactional producers that might lay idle for the broker’s transactional.id.expiration.ms. With current kafka-clients, this can cause a ProducerFencedException without a rebalance. By setting the maxAge to less than transactional.id.expiration.ms, the factory will refresh the producer if it is past its max age.

How ie. where can `maxAge` be configured for the default producer factory?

Answer (score 0):

I used the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer` which seems to work:

```
@Bean
public DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer producerFactoryCustomizer() {
    return (producerFactory) -> producerFactory.setMaxAge(Duration.ofDays(1));
}
```

This should be in a `@Configuration` class.

Comment: This is what I've implemented in the meantime too, but it didn't achieve the desired result which is avoiding producer id expiration which results in InvalidPidMappingException after one week.

Answer (score 0):

If you using stream binder you can set `maxAge` in this way too

```
@Bean
KafkaTransactionManager customKafkaTransactionManager(BinderFactory binder) {
    KafkaMessageChannelBinder kafka = (KafkaMessageChannelBinder)binder.getBinder("kafka1", MessageChannel.class);
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]> producerFactory = (DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]>) kafka.getTransactionalProducerFactory();

    producerFactory.setMaxAge(Duration.ofSeconds(60));

    return new KafkaTransactionManager(producerFactory);
}
```